# rails rendering but ajax fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

This is my ajax

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: '/posts/product_list.json',
    data: {sub_cat_id: sub_category_id},
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
                console.log('success');
        },
        error: function(data){
            console.log('failed');
        }
    });
```

Here is my controller action

```
respond_to :json,only: :product_list
def product_list
    @products = Product.find_by_sub_category_id params[:sub_cat_id]
    respond_with @products
  end
```

my product_list.json.erb file has

`test response`

While inspecting network link shows `test` but my console show `failed`

**Here is my console output**

```
Started GET "/posts/product_list.json?sub_cat_id=41" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-10-02 21:21:47 +0530
Processing by PostsController#product_list as JSON
  Parameters: {"sub_cat_id"=>"41"}
  Product Load (0.8ms)  SELECT "products".* FROM "products" WHERE "products"."sub_category_id" = 41 LIMIT 1
  Rendered posts/product_list.json.erb (0.1ms)
Completed 200 OK in 81ms (Views: 14.5ms | ActiveRecord: 4.1ms | Solr: 0.0ms)
```

**Working controller**

This is working

```
respond_to do |format|
      format.json { render json: { products: @products}}
    end
```

But unable to render `product_list.json.erb`

Do you have any idea.

Comment: Check your rails logs, what it has to say?

Comment: @techvineet I have included my console output. I doesn't showing any exception. can you please check it

Comment: Yes, it is returning just fine. So, you are saying error callback get executed on response? Make sure one thing that the AJAX is expecting JSON response. So, in case your JSON is not correct it could execute error callback.

Comment: @techvineet I could not find where i am wrong. can you help

Comment: can you post the content of posts/product_list.json.erb

Comment: I don't have any dynamic contents right now. I just have a word test` in `product.json.erb`. When i click `post_list.json?sub_cat_id=41` `chrome inspect network` it shows `test`. But my console response is failed

Comment: I m wondering when you have respond_with @products why it is looking for product.json.erb? Just try to return <%={:result => "true"}.to_json%>

Comment: Where to add this return

Comment: I mean just try to print this <%={:result => "true"}.to_json.html_safe%> instead of a line in json.erb file

Comment: getting something like this `{&quot;result&quot;:&quot;true&quot;}`.

Comment: Yes, this is the right way of doing it. It will just render products as json and will not expect product.json.erb

Comment: @techvineet What i actually need is. I need all the products as a list and i need to display it in dropdown through ajax jquery. How can i achieve it

Comment: @techvineet any suggestion please